Are we becoming better over time?
Does our moral sense evolve over time as Pinker contends? It seems that history bears this out.
However, the popular view of "O tempora, O mores!" still seems prevalent. So, are we becoming better?
In The Better Angels of our Nature, Pinker refers to Lincoln's phrase meaning moral sense. He does this in the context of reduced violence over time combined with greater sensitivity to violence.
For the avoidance of doubt, the question is about morality. I express no opinion, however it is difficult to employ neutral terms when discussing morality. I prefer answers to comments.

Hard to believe... wars are becoming "better" for sure.

"Evolve" is a neutral term, it does not mean getting "better". Pinker gives evidence that moral sentiments do evolve, whether that is for the "better" is in the eye of the beholder. Although it is not too surprising that our evolving sentiments approve of the direction they are evolving.

Don't you think that the answers to your question are completely opinion-based? The term "Our moral sense" is much too vague. And who decides what "the popular view" is and whether it is right or wrong?

If I could. I'd "bounty" your comment @MauroALLEGRANZA!

I agree that this is opinion-based. I'm also not sure that Steven Pinker would argue our moral sense is improving--his argument seems to be that our moral sense is static (at least on the timescales of a few hundred or thousand years), but structural and economic changes are leading to less violence and more peace.

If you wanted to make it less opinion-based, I might edit the question to ask for specifically arguments in favor or as rebuttal to specific claims Steven Pinker makes. For instance, "What are some arguments against Steven Pinker's claim that structural and economic changes are making human society less violent?"--but at that point, it seems like a political, economic or skeptics.SE question, not a philosophical one.

I don't see why this was closed. Peter Singer had a clear critetia for 'moral progress', & in most places most of the time would say we have been making that progress

@CriglCragl Thank you and to all who voted to re-open. . Apparently, I expressed an opinion by referring to moral sense.

According to two prominent thinkers, Steven Pinker, a Canadian psycholinguist and popularizer of scientific discourse, and Edward O. Wilson, entymologist turned professor emeritus of sociobiology and eusociality, yes.
First, Pinker argues in The Better Angels of Our Nature, that as we continue to grow in population on earth, we have transformed from ignorant, war-like tribes to a highly organized global society that through the lens of statistics is better educated, more liberal, and less violent. Certainly "better" in this regard presupposes that improvement are generally inline with the modern political liberalism as political scientists use the term. (In the US, the term has become a disparagement and is equated with certain excesses.) From WP:

he Better Angels of Our Nature: Why Violence Has Declined is a 2011 book by Steven Pinker, in which the author argues that violence in the world has declined both in the long run and in the short run and suggests explanations as to why this has occurred.1 The book uses data documenting declining violence across time and geography. This paints a picture of massive declines in the violence of all forms, from war, to improved treatment of children. He highlights the role of nation-state monopolies on force, of commerce (making other people become more valuable alive than dead), of increased literacy and communication (promoting empathy), as well as a rise in a rational problem-solving orientation as possible causes of this decline in violence. He notes that paradoxically, our impression of violence has not tracked this decline, perhaps because of increased communication,2 and that further decline is not inevitable, but is contingent on forces harnessing our better motivations such as empathy and increases in reason.

Secondly, in the Social Conquest of Earth, Wilson lays out the argument that human beings are more eusocial than ever, and that it is our propensity to be moral and organize that has assured our dominance over all other lifeforms on the planet. Such a claim from the father of sociobiology is not without controversy, as it invokes classical meta-narratives about human progress (SEP). From WP:

Wilson argues, building on the paper "The evolution of eusociality" (2010) by Wilson, Martin Nowak and Corina Tarnita in Nature, for more importance of group selection and against the idea of kin selection.

Of course, if religious absolutists are to believed, the world is going straight to tell in a hand basket, and has been since God or gods created the world. It is a common theme of many world religions that humans are essentially flawed and society is ultimately headed for a predestined doom as presented in many eschatological accounts. From WP:

Eschatology (/ˌɛskəˈtɒlədʒi/ ⓘ; from Ancient Greek ἔσχατος (éskhatos) 'last' and -logy) concerns expectations of the end of present age, human history, or the world itself.1 The end of the world or end times2 is predicted by several world religions (both Abrahamic and non-Abrahamic), which teach that negative world events will reach a climax. Belief that the end of the world is imminent is known as apocalypticism, and over time has been held both by members of mainstream religions and by doomsday cults. In the context of mysticism, the term refers metaphorically to the end of ordinary reality and to reunion with the divine. Religions treat eschatology as a future event prophesied in sacred texts or in folklore.

So, the answer really to the question is mired in an extensive and wide-ranging philosophical exploration of one's Weltanschauung. If one starts out being indoctrinated with Biblical literalism, for instance, it's hard to escape the conclusion that the Book of Revelation is a foregone conclusion, and that gay marriage is simply a signal that the world is about to collapse. If one is an atheist and believes that the Enlightenment is a sign humans are entering a golden age of reason and Scientific Progress (SEP), then one might harbor the hope that LCARS and the Federation of Planets is right around the corner as the aliens are about to bring us into the Galactic Fold. Ultimately, prognostications are notoriously easy to make and difficult to master, so whether or not humans are better, more moral, or are on some broader narrative of progress is difficult to say.

Right, I don't really care why people do helpful things, or how they feel about it, as long as they do them. Hate it like Hell, but be good.
